# why driving an I/O through the bit-banding region is slower than accessing direct registers?

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

so I was reading through this book called [Mastering STM32](https://leanpub.com/mastering-stm32-2nd) until I came to page 216 in which the author was talking about GPIO speed in stm32f4, so he wrote a sample code that toggles a GPIO pin at high speed and this was his code:

```
int main(void) {

   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
 
   HAL_Init();

   __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

   /* Configure GPIO pin : PC8 */
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
   HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

   while(1) {
      GPIOC->ODR = 0x100;
      GPIOC->ODR = 0;
   }
}
```

and these are the results obtained from the oscilloscope according to the author:

[image]

where the delta T is about `65 ns`, however using the bit-banding region feature in stm32 with the following code:

```
...
volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_ODR = (((((uint32_t)0x40000000) + 0x00020000) + 0x0800) + 0x14);
volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_PIN8 = (uint32_t)BITBAND_PERI(GPIOC_ODR, 8);
...
while(1) {
   *GPIOC_PIN8 = 0x1;
   *GPIOC_PIN8 = 0;
}
```

resulted in the following figure on the oscilloscope:

[image]

where the deal T decreased to become 250 ns and the author didn't justify why but rather mentioned :

> Curiously, driving an I/O through the bit-banding region, using the same number of assembly
> instructions, dramatically reduces the switching frequency down to 4MHz

so is there any reason for using the bit-banding feature if it's slower and is there any explanation for why it's slower?

Comment: You should disassemble the code (or look at the `.list` file that CubeIDE generates by default). What optimisation level are you using? Is this something that you have actually seen or experienced, or is this just a question about the book?

Comment: @pmacfarlane, this is just a queston about the book as the writer claimed that bit-banding is slower for same number of assembly instructions without explaining why

Comment: @old_timer , thanks for your efforts and comments, one of my friends suggested that Bit band write operations convert internally to atomic read-modify-write operations which will always be slower than the write only of the direct version but I really don't know if this has a high impact on performance or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a fair comparison.  In the first example the entire register is written, while in the second the single bit is written without modifying adjacent bits.

If you had to do a read-modify-write to set the single bit, it would most likely take longer as well as not being *atomic* so not intrinsically thread safe.  The code you would have to add to make it thread safe would also add time, and may, if you use a critical section or disable interrupts affect the timing of the entire system.  Alternatively it may be that that internally a multi-cycle atomic read-modify-write is occurring.

For a semantically identical comparison, the first code might look like:

```
   while(1) 
   {
      __disable_irq()
      GPIOC->ODR |= 0x100;
      GPIOC->ODR &= ~0x100;
      __enable_irq() ;
   }
```

Which would most likely be slower - probably even without the thread safety.  Although to guarantee the timing you would not want any pre-emption safe or otherwise.

So the advantage of bit-banding is not so much the performance, though as described above in many practical cases it may be faster, but rather in the atomicity of the operation.

The danger of the author's unexplained observation is you might think that bit-banding has no merit because he is not comparing like for like.

As to why the individual bus transaction may be slower it it a shame perhaps that the author did not investigate further - he was taking the time to write a book after all, whereas you are trying to get stuff done.  To set himself up as an authority, to only then shrug and ignore it somewhat disappointing.

I might speculate that it is a bus architecture issue - Cortex-M has a "modified" Harvard architecture where code space and data space are normally on separate buses allowing a data and instruction fetch in parallel.  Further different STM32 series have separate buses for CCM, TCM, and multiple regular SRAM regions.  I wonder whether bit-banding introduces a bus- contention on some parts.

If you want to set multiple bits *simultaneously* then read-modify-write is the only way to get exactly synchronous bit transitions in any case, so bit-banding for I/O is useful (and fast) in only very specific situations.

One reason to avoid bit-banding is portability of code ot other targets.  It is ARM specific and implemented *optionally* on Cortex-M3 and M4, but is not present on M7 at all.